# How do I handle occupational skill points for fighting and firearms skills with unspecified specializations?

Tags: character-creation, call-of-cthulhu-7e

I'm noting an idiosyncrasy in some of the skills afforded by occupations, specifically the Firearms and Fighting skills.

For example - Sometimes, it will say "Fighting (Brawl)".  Other times it will just simply say "Fighting".

These 2 skills (Fighting and Firearms) appear to be overarching categorical terms for a wide variety of specializations, as evidenced by page 96 of the Investigator's Handbook:

> Some broad skills are broken into specializations. A player
> may spend skill points to purchase any skill specialization.
> The generic skill cannot be purchased. Thus a player may
> spend points in Fighting (Brawl) or Fighting (Spear) but
> not simply Fighting.

Does this mean that the player can choose whatever specialization they want?

If so, while it wouldn't really be all that lore-friendly, is there anything mechanically stopping, say, a Bounty Hunter (which only says Fighting and Firearms) from choosing Fighting (Flail) and Firearms (Artillery)?

Obviously, such a thing might be vetoed by the Keeper, which is fine, but I'm just trying to make sure that I understand the rule here.

Answer (score 2):

### You choose the specialization when it is not listed.

Several other career choices have unlisted Fighting specializations:

- Assassin
- Stage Actor
- Bank Robber
- Bootlegger
- Thug
- Street Punk
- Gangster Boss
- Gangster Underling
- Laborer, Unskilled
- Private Investigator
- Sailor, Naval
- Soldier/Marine
- Stuntman
- possibly more.

You can guess how most of these careers would come bundled with a particular type of fighting more specific than just *brawling*: the assassin is exemplary in this respect.

Also, note this excerpt from the Fighting skill description:

> A myriad of fighting styles exist, each with its own
> pros and cons. Martial arts are simply a way of developing
> a person’s Fighting skill. Decide how the character learned
> to fight, whether it be **formal military training, martial arts
> classes, or learned the hard way as a result of street-fighting.**
> The term "brawl" might feel too crude for a skilled martial
> artist and could be replaced (with Karate for example) if a
> player so wished.

Emphasis mine. These examples are all included on the list of careers with access to unspecialized Fighting. (Martial arts is absolutely Stuntman territory: think Jackie Chan or Bruce Lee.)

Clearly, the intent with unlisted Fighting specializations for these careers is to the player the opportunity to add a bit of flair to their character by choosing a specialization.